# Game not detecting collision with keybindings?

Tags: java, collision

So in my little side-scroller Java game I'm attempting to make collisions for my character against walls. I am using keybindings instead of key listeners because of the focusing issues it often caused. Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
 Action moveleft = new AbstractAction(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          if (moving==true&&offsetX!=2){
              offsetX=offsetX+2;
          }
      }
    };
```

The problem is that when a key is held down to make the character move, in the actionperformed method, it doesn't recheck the conditional statement that determines whether moving is true or false when the key is held down. This results in the character moving indefinitely through all walls until the key is released.

So why is this? What can I do to remedy it? If any more code is required from my program I can provide! Thanks!

This is an abridged version of my panel class where basically all of the collision takes place:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public static boolean moving=true;
    Player p1;
    public InputMap inputmap;
    public ActionMap actionmap;
    ArrayList<Level> Levels;

    Level level1;
    protected static int offsetX=0;
    protected static int offsetY=0;

    public Panel() {
        inputmap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputmap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "startright");
        inputmap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "startleft");
        inputmap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "stop");
        inputmap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "stop");
        actionmap = getActionMap();
        actionmap.put("startright", moveright);
        actionmap.put("startleft", moveleft);
        actionmap.put("startup", moveup);
        actionmap.put("startdown", movedown);
        actionmap.put("stop", stop);
    }
    //The game's main game loop
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (!running){
            startGame();
        }
        gameUpdate();
        repaint();
    }
    //Updates the game every iteration
    private void gameUpdate() {
        p1.update();
        for (int i = 0; i < Levels.size(); i++) {
            collide(p1, level1.Blocks.get(i));
        }
    }

    Action moveright = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //p1.setRight(e);
            if (moving==true&&offsetX!=-2){
                offsetX=offsetX-2;
            }
        }
    };

    Action moveleft = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //p1.setLeft(e);
            if (moving==true&&offsetX!=2){
                offsetX=offsetX+2;
            }
        }
    };

    Action moveup = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //p1.setUp(e);
            if (moving==true&&offsetY!=-1){
                offsetY=offsetY-1;
            }
        }
    };

    Action movedown = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //p1.setDown(e);
            if (moving==true&&offsetY!=1){
                offsetY=offsetY+1;
            }
        }
    };

    Action stop = new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //p1.stop(e);
            offsetX=0;
            offsetY=0;
        }
    };


    public void collide(Player p, Block b) {
        if (Math.abs(p.minX) < Math.abs(b.maxX)) {
            moving=false;   
        }
        else {
            //moving=true;
        }
    }
}
```

That is basically everything involving collision. I'm really just wondering why the actionPerformed method keeps adding to the offset even when `moving == false`.

Comment: Theres no where near enough code to determine the problem here. Could you post a small complete program that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I added some more of my code. If you want to see the full panel class I can do that, but this is a bit smaller.

Comment: Really the idea of a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is that it should be a bare minimum working example to show the problem. For example do you require all 5 actionmaps to get this problem? And could I copy and paste this into my IDE and see the problem?

Comment: Have you confirmed that moving *is* false, for example by including a print statement?

Comment: Your moveLeft action is different in both of your snippets - which one should it be?

Comment: Sorry about the differences in the two. I was doing some testing and forgot to change the statement back to offset+2. I think I fixed it now. And Richard I have included a print statement and it is coming back false right when I need it to be, but the sprite continues to move as long as the key is held. I don't mind you copying into an IDE. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: You set moving to false, but you never actually check it...

Comment: "moving" is checked in the snippet that I provided, which is the action I was initially testing it with.